# How do we write a SQL query for below

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm having a table MyTable with 3 columns - Main, Merge, Count

```
Main   Merge    Count
1      1        11
2      1        7
3      1        1
4      1        4
90     1        3
2      2        7
3      2        1
4      2        4
3      3        1
4      3        4
9      10       17
10     10       14
11     11       16
12     11       1
13     11       21
12     12       1
13     12       21
```

My Resultant should be:

```
Main   Merge    Count
1      1        26  (Add up all counts based on Merge 11+7+1+4+3)
9      10       31  (17+14)
11     11       38  (16+1+21)
```

Logic:
1. Get all the Sum(Count) based on Merge

2. Check all the Main column associated with a Merge (eg 1,2,3,4,90 is associated with Merge 1). Keep only min(Main) number - in this case its 1
3. Do not display any records with 2,3,4,90 as it was already considered in calc. Hence Main Col with 2,3,4,90 would not be shown

For Merge 10 - Main 9 and 10 are associated. We need to only display Main 9 but the total would be of combined total of Merge 10

For Merge 11 - Main 11,12 and 13 are associated. We need to have combine total of 11 (i.e. 16+1+21 = 38). Main 12, 13 would not show up in result

Comment: Common recursive CTE which starts from `main = merge`.

Comment: What about the rows with `Merge` of `2` or `3`? Can you explain why they are excluded?

Comment: Or Minimum ? Why is 9 minimum ?

Comment: When we consider Merge say 1 - We have associated 1,2,3,4,90 with it. Need to ignore 2,3,4,90 from Main as well as Merge as the count is already considered in Main - 1, Merge - 1
Now the next series is of Merge 10. We need to show Main 9 and the count

Comment: The question is quite clear to me.

Comment: Hi @AmritpalSingh I see you have updated your question, great, but also do show others what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eliminate the previously counted rows using `EXISTS` and use simple aggregation for the `SUM`;

```
SELECT MIN([Main]) [Main], [Merge], SUM([Count]) [Count]
FROM myTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM myTable a 
  WHERE a.[Main] = myTable.[Main]
    AND a.[Merge] < myTable.[Merge]
)
GROUP BY [Merge]
ORDER BY [Merge]

Main    Merge   Count
1        1      26
9       10      31
11      11      38
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/78bd99/1).

Alternately, you could use a common table expression to count each time a certain value for `Main` occurs in order of the lowest to the higest value for `Merge`, and only use the first occurrence;

```
;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Main] ORDER BY [Merge]) rn  FROM myTable
)
SELECT MIN([Main]) [Main], [Merge], SUM([Count]) [Count]
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY [Merge]
ORDER BY [Merge]
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/00be0/1)

Comment: Joachim - You are simple awesome ! Appreciate everyone's help whoever have tried resolving the issue.